# How to put 2 references together example According....(Smith, 1998; Bennet, 2001)

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I want to do this:

```
According....(Smith, 1998; Bennet, 2001).
```

But I ended up:

```
According to the table these definition \textcite{journal1}; \textcite{journal2}
```

[image]

The full MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{journal1,
  title={journal123},
  author={McIntosh, Gerald C and Brown, Susan H and Rice, Ruth R and Thaut, Michael H},
  journal={Journal of Neurology, Neurosurgery \& Psychiatry},
  volume={62},
  number={1},
  pages={22--26},
  year={1997},
}

@article{journal2,
  title={journal123456},
  author={Abc, Def, GhI},
  journal={Journal of Neurology, Neurosurgery \& Psychiatry},
  volume={62},
  number={1},
  pages={22--26},
  year={1997},
}


\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear, 
  backend=biber, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % \jobname to use the bib file created with filecontents
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear} % <======================================
    {}
    {(\bibhyperref{\printdate})}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite} % <=====================================
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{(\usebibmacro{cite}})}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
\renewbibmacro{textcite}{% <============================================
   \bibhyperref{%
   \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
   \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
   }%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

The table these definition \textcite{journal1}; \textcite{journal2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the correct way would be to put all reference into the same argument of a single command

```
\parencite{sigfridsson,geer}
```

or the multicite

```
\parencites[380]{sigfridsson}[23-25]{geer}
```

if you need explicit pre- or postnotes for all entries.

But with the redefinition of  `\parencite` in the MWE the output will be subpar. The redefinition in the MWE has another issue: Try `\parencite[see][380]{sigfridsson}`. The parentheses are hard-coded directly into the macro in a location where they can not cover the entire output of the `\parencite` when it involves multiple citations or pre- and postnotes.

```
\printtext[bibhyperref]{(\usebibmacro{cite}})}
```

I can offer the following redefinition of `\parencite` that produces usable output by moving the command for parentheses into the pre-code of the cite command, but that doesn't link the outer parentheses.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear, 
  backend=biber, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
    {}
    {(\bibhyperref{\printdate})}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
\renewbibmacro{textcite}{%
   \bibhyperref{%
   \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
   \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
   }%
}%
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
The table these definition \parencite{sigfridsson,geer}

The table these definition \parencites[380]{sigfridsson}[23-25]{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The table these definition (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998; Geer, 1985)//The table these definition (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998, p. 380; Geer, 1985, pp. 23–25)]

Comment: thanks. I tried `according to \parencite{journal1,journal2}` using my MWE, the output is `according to (McIntosh et al., 1997); (Abc, 1997)`. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: @aan Yes, you get "(McIntosh et al., 1997); (Abc, 1997)", but I thought you want "(McIntosh et al., 1997; Abc, 1997)"

Comment: thanks. I need `"(McIntosh et al., 1997; Abc, 1997)"`. I forget to edit the `\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]`. Now, using my MWE, it shows `according to `(McIntosh et al., 1997; Abc, 1997)` which is correct. Thanks

Comment: by the way, how do you get to know all these `\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]`?

Comment: @aan The commands are documented in the `biblatex` manual, but the exact definitions vary from style to style and can be found in `biblatex.def`, `standard.bbx` as well as `<style>.bbx` (bibliography style) and `<style>.cbx` (citation style). In this case `authoryear.cbx` would be the relevant file. (You can find the location of those files by typing `kpsewhich <file>` in the command line, e.g. `kpsewhich authoryear.cbx` points me to `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/authoryear.cbx`).

Comment: thanks. very complicated

Answer (score 1):

I used `natbib` to get you what would work

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{journal1,
  title={journal123},
  author={McIntosh, Gerald C and Brown, Susan H and Rice, Ruth R and Thaut, Michael H},
  journal={Journal of Neurology, Neurosurgery \& Psychiatry},
  volume={62},
  number={1},
  pages={22--26},
  year={1997},
}

@article{journal2,
  title={journal123456},
  author={Abc, Def, GhI},
  journal={Journal of Neurology, Neurosurgery \& Psychiatry},
  volume={62},
  number={1},
  pages={22--26},
  year={1997},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

Blah \citep{journal1, journal2}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, it came out to be `The table these definition (McIntosh et al. (1997); Abc (1997))` which have 2 brackets inside.

Comment: I want to have `The table these definition (McIntosh et al., 1997; Abc, 1997)`

Comment: Using `natbib` would be the easiest way to get you what you want. I apologize for misunderstanding your question.

Comment: no problem. I actually didn't use `natbib` as I am using `biblatex`, and if I want to change to `natbib`, i have to change all again. So I am looking for another way