# Why double ((Smith, 1998);(Berrnet, 2001)) in referencing

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

I get lost as I try to use the answer given on my MWE, previously is working. Not sure why now is not working.

I am using answer in [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507332/how-to-put-2-references-together-example-according-smith-1998-bennet-2001/507347?noredirect=1#comment1282006_507347)

[image]
    \RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

```
@article{journal1,
  title={journal123},
  author={McIntosh, Gerald C and Brown, Susan H and Rice, Ruth R and Thaut, Michael H},
  journal={Journal of Neurology, Neurosurgery \& Psychiatry},
  volume={62},
  number={1},
  pages={22--26},
  year={1997},
}

@article{journal2,
  title={journal123456},
  author={Abc, Def, GhI},
  journal={Journal of Neurology, Neurosurgery \& Psychiatry},
  volume={62},
  number={1},
  pages={22--26},
  year={1997},
}


\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear, 
  backend=biber, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % \jobname to use the bib file created with filecontents

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear} % <======================================
    {}
    {(\bibhyperref{\printdate})}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{(\usebibmacro{cite}})}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
\renewbibmacro{textcite}{% <============================================
   \bibhyperref{%
   \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
   \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
   }%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

The table these definition \parencite{journal1, journal2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I can post my answer.
I found my mistake:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Under:

```
 \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
```

Original is

```
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{(\usebibmacro{cite}})}
```